# How to use grep to match domain names?

Tags: linux, grep, regex, string, parsing

I have a list of urls like:

```
hxxp://url.com/subpage.html
hxxp://www.url2.com/index.php
hxxp://subdomain.url3.com/somepage.php
...
```

How can I use grep to match the domain names only?

All the urls have a / after the domain. And there are a lot of tlds, not sure how many, the list is quite big.

Answer (score 5):

In order to use non-greedy regexes with `grep` you will need to use the `-P` option and the `-o` option outputs only the matching portion. You will also need to use lookarounds so that part of the match is not included in the output.

```
grep -Po '.*?//\K.*?(?=/)'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'hxxp://subdomain.url3.com/somepage.php' | grep -Po '.*?//\K.*?(?=/)'
subdomain.url3.com
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a great place to test your regex skills [here](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/regextutor.shtml).
The expression should look like

`.*?//(.*)/`

You will need to loop through all the results.  On the page that I have given you, you can put this expression in and a web address and it will then show you what matched.  Also remember that you will then have the captured variable for only a limited time.

Comment: That won't work for `http://url.com/directory/page.html`

Answer (score 0):

If they only have one TLD after the domain then this should work (I'm assuming you want to exclude the subdomain):

```
[^\./]*\.[^\./]*/
```

It still has the trailing slash though, but you can just pipe that through `sed`.